# Incorrect data from google analytics in Power BI

Tags: google-app-engine, powerbi

I am having Power BI pro and working on the company Google analytics. When I am trying to fetch number of users on my website from Google analytics then its showing wrong data. And when I directly open google analytics data variation is too huge only in case of number of users.

[image]

Comment: just a question, did you loaded data or just previewing it? also are you fetching all the columns or you excluded some

Comment: I have loaded these two columns only shall i have to load all the columns from this directory?

Comment: Try loading all the columns and check in your table if you have all the data and then maybe you can remove columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Analytics UI, try to run an unsampled report for the number of users with the given time frame. The number of users from the ordinary webpage UI is generated from sampling and varies from what you have in Power BI or BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you are facing an issue of sampling.
So Power bi's connector for google analytics has a sampling issue and an API Calls limit. The standard limitations and quotas for Google Analytics API requests are documented in Limits and Quotas on API Requests. However, Power BI Desktop and Power BI service allow you to use the following enhanced number of queries.

Queries per day: 1,500,000 Queries per 100 seconds: 4,000

Might be better to connect Google analytics to a data warehouse such as Google BigQuery, which will help you get access to historical data that you won't be able to get with Power bi's connector. I'd suggest using a third-party connector.